# Google Chrome Browser does not display the images from Local network or local host?

Tags: google-chrome, android

Edit :

in the html source I have thigs like :

```
<img src="./images/someimage.jpg" />
```

This displays fine  IE/FireFox would display the images coming from URL's like "http://mypc" or "http://localhost" or ip adress on the netwrok , google chrome on Galaxy, Windows Machine, or google Android  will not display the images.

After having burned too many hours trying various CSS, image src tag, html document description  tricks, I have given up.

During my search I found (and lost) the link to chrome forums regarding this issue that seemed to say it is just so by users.

Anyone has any more information on weather it is possible to view images on local host/computer name on netwrok or ip adress?

Comment: What webserver do you have running on your machine?

Comment: I can see them fine with Google Chrome. However the protocol is not http. it is a file. file://localhost/..../something.jpg. Remember to have forward slash (/) instead of back slash.

Comment: @airza : Webserver is IIS7 and IIS Express , one for the netwrok and one for the development.

Comment: @geeth : Sorry, the images are not displayed in the web page, but when I copy the image link and paste in the browser then the single image is displayed fine with http : // mycomputer/images/image1.jpg    the spaces are because SO, keeps turning it to a link

Answer (score 1):

try using `http://localhost/resouce.jpg` instead of `http:/localhost/resouce.jpg`

Comment: Updated the question, did not realise the typos.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above (where you say if you put h11p://mycomputer/images/image1.jpg it works) and your question (where you put image URL of ./images/someimage.jpg), my guess is that you have a problem with the relativeness (lacking a better word) of your URLs.

E.G.

if your page is at h11p://mycomputer/folder/page.html and you use the relative URL ./images/image1.jpg to source the image then your browser will look in h11p://mycomputer/folder/images/image1.jpg to find that image.

This can also happen with URLs that have been rewritten to include additional slashes.

Solutions are to use either a url that is absolute on the site e.g. /images/image1.jpg (omitting the leading .) or to use a URL that is absolute to the host e.g. h11p://mycomputer/images/image1.jpg

The first solution is preferable because it will continue to work when you change the host-name/domain-name of the site.

** read http where I write h11p

Comment: And if that isn't the problem and you're still stuck I suggest that you post more problem (html) code. include the URLs you use to access the page and the url that works to access the image. (feel free to obfuscate your hostname if you feel it worth while, but don't change any paths)